# Where can I find comprehensive and current lists of international naming disputes

Tags: geospatial, politics

I'm looking for any comprehensive information on naming disputes. Outside of Wikipedia (also not a bad source) I haven't found anything. Some examples: Persian Gulf vs. Arabian Gulf, the East Sea vs. Sea of Japan vs. Sea of Korea etc., Guayana Esequibo vs. all provinces administered by Guyana.

Comment: geonames.org has a list of 'alternate names' for several million named geographical entities, but alternate names aren't always disputed names, so not sure how helpful this is.